# How Convert year integer column to Date column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the column `YrSold` into a date column.

```py
Id                  int64
MSSubClass       category
MSZoning         category
LotFrontage         int32
LotArea           float64
                   ...   
MoSold              int32
YrSold              int32
SaleType         category
SaleCondition    category
SalePrice           int32
Length: 81, dtype: object
```

I need to have this column into a date object, but my data doesn't have specific days (or *sometimes* months). I've tried the following methods, but they don't seem to work:

```py
df['YrSold'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YrSold'], format='%y')
df['YrSold'] = df['YrSold'].dt.strftime('%y')
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Does it work if you add an option `errors='ignore'` to `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: `df['YrSold'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YrSold'], format='%Y')` would be enough. And you would get `2020` -> `2020-01-01` as a date.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work. Both `errors='ignore'` and `df['YrSold'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YrSold'], format='%Y')` will result in the following error:
`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

Comment: `df['YrSold_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YrSold'], format='%Y')` works on my end. Please add more details to the question, so that we could repro the issue.

Comment: Are there any nan values?

Comment: Ok, nvm, it seems to work now if I do every column seperatly. I was trying to perform changes with a array of columns in order to make it an one-liner, but I didn't consider that that could've been the problem.